# Cannot import name 'linear_util' from 'jax'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, importerror, jax

I'm trying to reproduce the experiments of the S5 model, https://github.com/lindermanlab/S5, but I encountered some issues when solving the environment. When I'm running the shell script`./run_lra_cifar.sh`, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Path/S5/run_train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from s5.train import train
  File "/Path/S5/s5/train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .train_helpers import create_train_state, reduce_lr_on_plateau,\
  File "/Path/train_helpers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flax.training import train_state
  File "/Path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flax/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flax/core/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .axes_scan import broadcast
  File "/Path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flax/core/axes_scan.py", line 22, in <module>
    from jax import linear_util as lu
ImportError: cannot import name 'linear_util' from 'jax' (/Path/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/__init__.py)
```

I'm running this on an RTX4090 and my CUDA version is 11.8. My jax version is 0.4.25 and jaxlib version is 0.4.25+cuda11.cudnn86

I first tried to install the dependencies using the author's

```
pip install -r requirements_gpu.txt
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in my case since I can't even`import jax`. So I installed jax according to the instructions on https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
by typing

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda11_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

So far I've tried:

1. Using a older GPU(3060 and 2070)
2. Downgrading python to 3.9

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`jax.linear_util` was [deprecated in JAX v0.4.16](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-16-sept-18-2023) and [removed in JAX v0.4.24](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-24-feb-6-2024).

It appears that `flax` is the source of the `linear_util` import, meaning that you are using an older flax version with a newer jax version.

To fix your issue, you'll either need to install an older version of JAX which still has `jax.linear_util`, or update to a newer version of `flax` which is compatible with more recent JAX versions.